# Parse a YAML list of dictionaries in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, for-loop, yaml-cpp

I have the following yaml (a simplified version of my case):

```
---
my_list:
    - item1:
        name: name1
    - item2:
        name: name2
```

And then I am trying to parse it like this using C++ and YAML-CPP:

```
for (const auto & p : node["my_list"]) {
    std::cout << p.IsMap() << std::endl;
    YAML::Node key = p.first;
    YAML::Node value = p.second;
}
```

This apparently works (`IsMap()` returns 1), but as soon as I do: `p.first.as<std::string>();` it crashes. How should I parse this?

On the contrary, if I do:

```
for (auto it = node.begin(); it != node.end(); ++it) {
    YAML::Node key = it->first;
    YAML::Node value = it->second;
    std::cout << key.as<std::string>() << std::endl;
}
```

And the output here is `my_list`, so I can continue the parsing.

My question is: how can I parse using the `C++11` range for loop? Thanks

Comment: are you sure that p is a pair<YAML::Node, YAML::Node>, and not something that has a first and second that are convertible to YAML::Nodes?

Comment: No, I am not sure. It is not clear for me how YAML-CPP library. I tried other things such as `p.as<std::string>()`. If I do a dictionary of dictionaries it is easy to parse, but a list for some reason is not.

Comment: I finally found the answer, although I do not know why! It seems that `for (const auto & p : node["my_list"])` returns the list itself, so you can do `p[0], p[1]...'. The dictionary is an element of the list, so another for loop is required for every dictionary: `for (const auto & elem : p)`. If nobody provides a better answer with a better explanation I will write this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're iterating through a YAML sequence, the entries you get are the entries in the sequence, *not* key/value pairs:

```
for (const auto& p : node["my_list"]) {
    std::cout << p.IsMap() << "\n";
    // Here 'p' is a map node, not a pair.
    for (const auto& key_value : p) {
      // Now 'key_value' is a key/value pair, so you can read it:
      YAML::Node key = key_value.first;
      YAML::Node value = key_value.second;
      std::string s = key.as<std::string>();
      // ....
    }
}
```

The reason that `p` has fields `first` and `second` is that iteration in yaml-cpp is overloaded: you can iterate through sequences (where the entries are nodes) or maps (where the entries are key/value pairs). In each case, the other's syntax is available statically, but won't give you any reasonable information at runtime.

Comment: Thanks a lot! However, I do not understand why if `p` is a map node, element of the sequence, why can't I do `p[0].first.as<std::string>()`?

Comment: If `p` is a map node, then `p[0]` refers to the value associated with the key `0`, which isn't what you're referring to. What is your question?